# Bypassing id from view to controller to create a model with relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller, mongoid

i am trying to create a menu for a restaurant. A menu has to have a restaurant, but i dont know how to bypass the id or how to solve the problem.

here is my route:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
resources :restaurants do
end
resources :menus
end
```

this is my restaurant model:

```
has_many :menus, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :menus
```

my menu model:

```
class Menu
include Mongoid::Document

belongs_to :restaurant
accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurant

validates :name, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :restaurant, presence: true

field :name, type: String
field :description, type: String
end
```

from the restaurants show.erb im calling this:

```
<%= link_to 'new Menu', new_menu_path(@restaurant) %>
```

in the menu controller i tried to put this into the new or create method:

```
@resti = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
```

but it is not working.. i really dont know how i should solve this.. can anybody tell me how i can do that?

this is the error because of the Restaurant.find

```
Problem: Calling Document.find with nil is invalid. Summary: Document.find 
expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document 
if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are 
provided. Resolution: Most likely this is caused by passing parameters 
directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or 
the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.
```

thank you in advanced

update: when i do as jef said nested route

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :menus
end
```

i get this error in app/views/menus/new.html.erb

```
undefined method `menus_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb2937484c8>:0x007fb290d704e8>

<%= form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
<% if @menu.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@menu.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this menu from being saved:</h2>
```

Comment: if you look in the rails server, what are your params?

Comment: how do you mean that? where do i see that?

Comment: in the terminal where you've typed `rails s` to run the server, you can see the actions of that server when you run the browser - you should be able to find the params that are sent when you click the 'new menu' link

Comment: do you mean something like this? Started GET "/52780a7f656172501c0a0000/menus/new"

Comment: you're in the right place - you should see a hash called params

Comment: ahh.. Parameters: {"locale"=>"52780a7f656172501c0a0000"} is this it thinks its a localization code?

Comment: well it's telling you that your params are not what you expect them to be.  next step is to figure out why that is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to explicitly pass the `restaurant_id` parameter to the path helper :

```
<%= link_to 'new Menu', new_menu_path(restaurant_id: @restaurant) %>
```

Another is to nest the `menus` resource into the `restaurants` one into your routes :

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :menus
end
```

Then in your view :

```
<%= link_to 'new Menu', new_restaurant_menu_path(@restaurant) %>
```

**EDIT**

In the `MenusController`, add a filter to automatically assign the `@restaurant` :

```
before_filter :assign_restaurant

...
private
def assign_restaurant
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
end
```

Comment: Hi Jef, your first solution i get the same error at this position @pipao = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id]) and my call: <%= link_to 'new Menu', new_menu_path(restaurant_id: @restaurant) %>

Comment: on the second one i get this error: undefined method `menus_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb2937484c8>:0x007fb290d704e8> on 
 <%= form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
    <% if @menu.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@menu.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this menu from being saved:</h2>

Comment: In the first case, did you added the `Restaurant.find...` in both `new` and `create` methods ? In the second, the issue is with your `form_for` I guess, try with `form_for(@restaurant, @menu)`.

Comment: in first, no, just in create, and second, when i add this, i get: irst argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: In any case, if you nest the resource you'll have to assign the `@restaurant` instance variable properly (try copy-paste first, then switch to a `before_filter`).

Comment: do you mean like this: attr_accessor :restaurant and the set it for example in the show method of the restaurant?

Comment: sorry.. i do not get it where to put that.. :(

Comment: but in the form_for i had to put this: form_for([@restaurant, @menu])